# Error "Cannot add foreign key constraint" al relacionar dos campos varchar

Tags: mysql

Estoy aprendiendo sobre bases de datos relacionales y tengo un problema a la hora de relacionar dos tablas con una auxiliar con una relacion de muchos a muchos.

Estoy intentando relacionar dos tablas que tienen un campo varchar como clave primaria generando una tabla auxiliar pero me da error `Cannot add foreign key constraint`

Tengo una serie de dudas:
1º ¿Es posible hacer esta relación con un tipo de campo varchar? lo he probado cambiando los campos por INT y si funciona correctamente.

2º He probado a relacionar una tabla con otra de 1 a muchos y con el tipo de dato varchar si funciona.

Adjunto imagen del modelo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias y un saludo.

**EDIT1:**

Copio la creación se la sentencia.

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema inver
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema inver
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `inver` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `inver` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inver`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inver`.`users` (
  `id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(230) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inver`.`greenhouse`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inver`.`greenhouse` (
  `fiwareServicePath` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `metros` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lugar` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `users_id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_greenhouse1_users1_idx` (`users_id_user` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`fiwareServicePath`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_greenhouse1_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id_user`)
    REFERENCES `inver`.`users` (`id_user`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inver`.`sensors`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inver`.`sensors` (
  `entityId` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `sensor_name` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entityId`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `inver`.`sensors_has_greenhouse`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inver`.`sensors_has_greenhouse` (
  `sensors_entityId` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `greenhouse_fiwareServicePath` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath`, `sensors_entityId`),
  INDEX `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_greenhouse1_idx` (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_sensors1_idx` (`sensors_entityId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_sensors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sensors_entityId`)
    REFERENCES `inver`.`sensors` (`entityId`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_greenhouse1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath`)
    REFERENCES `inver`.`greenhouse` (`fiwareServicePath`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

**EDIT2**

Añado el error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `inver`.`sensors_has_greenhouse`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inver`.`sensors_has_greenhouse` (
          `sensors_entityId` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `greenhouse_fiwareServicePath` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath`, `sensors_entityId`),
          INDEX `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_greenhouse1_idx` (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_sensors1_idx` (`sensors_entityId` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_sensors1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`sensors_entityId`)
            REFERENCES `inver`.`sensors` (`entityId`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_sensors_has_greenhouse_greenhouse1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`greenhouse_fiwareServicePath`)
            REFERENCES `inver`.`greenhouse` (`fiwareServicePath`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
        COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Comment: Usar campos `VARCHAR` para las relacioenes es posible, pero no es recomendable. Ayudaría a una respuesta que pusieras las sentencias `CREATE TABLE` que te están dando el error. Ten en cuenta que en una relación muchos a muchos las tres columnas que intervienen deben ser del mismo tipo de datos y del mismo tamaño. Y que si ya existen datos en las tablas que violan las restricciones no podrás crearlas... una posibilidad es apagar las restricciones antes de agregar las relaciones entre las tablas y luego encenderlas de nuevo.

Comment: Buenas, acabo de editar el POST con la sentencia. @A.Cedano

Comment: las respuestas es, si es posible, pero no es para nada recomendable. Si quieres poner el error que estas recibiendo para que podamos poner una respuesta a lo que realmente pasa, podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Acabo de subir el error, gracias por la ayuda.@gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza siempre las relaciones con un identificador numérico, es mucho mejor a la hora de ordenar los datos en la tabla N-M. Sí que es posible, como te han indicado, pero no es lo más recomendable, amén de que no tendría mucha lógica ya que tú quieres que al ver esa tabla haya un orden lógico de los datos, y eso lo consigues ordenando esa relación con una ID que aglutine ambas claves foráneas.

Un ejemplo rápido que tengo por ahí de tabla N-M:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `ra33` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE 
latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `ra33`;

CREATE TABLE `empresas` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `fundacion` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `empresa_producto` (
  `id_empresa` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `precio_base` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: que tiene que ver el orden de la tabla con el id numerico? las tablas no estan ordenadas, salvo que uno las ordene explicitamente al hacer un query. Tal vez estoy entendiendo algo mal o lo estas explicando mal?

Comment: No, yo hablo a la hora de plasmarlas en pantalla, poder ordenarlas por el ID para que quede más claro, me he explicado mal, disculpa.

Comment: A la hora de plasmarlas en una pantalla es el mismo problema, las va a ordenar un sort. y probablemente las vas a ordenar por nombre o apellido ;) y el Id no importa..

Comment: Sí sí, tienes razón, el orden al fin y al cabo acaba siendo muy personal. Y también pones filtros al final.

Answer (score 3):

El error es que las tablas relacionadas no tienen la misma propiedad `COLLATE`.

La documentación dice lo siguiente al respecto:

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must
>   have similar data types. The size and sign of integer types must be
>   the same. The length of string types need not be the same. **For
>   nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation
>   must be the same**.
>
> ---
>
> Las columnas correspondientes en la clave externa y la clave a la que se hace referencia deben tener tipos de datos similares. El tamaño
>   y el signo de los tipos enteros deben ser iguales. La longitud de los
>   tipos string no tiene que ser la misma. **Para las columnas de cadena
>   no binarias (caracteres), el conjunto de caracteres (`CHARSET`) y la
>   intercalación (`COLLATE`) deben ser iguales**.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). 
>   (La traducción y las negritas son mías.)</sub>

Así la tablas:

`sensors` y `sensors_has_greenhouse` tienen el siguiente `COLLATE` en el `CREATE TABLE`:

```
COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci
```

Pero `sensors_has_greenhouse` se relaciona con **la tabla `greenhouse`, que no tiene `COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci`**.

**Dos columnas no binarias (columnas del tipo String como lo es `VARCHAR`) no pueden participar de una relación entre tablas si tienen diferente `COLLATE`.** Eso es precisamente lo que ocurre en tu caso.

### Solución

O bien le otorgas `COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci` a la tabla `greenhouse`  (y a `users`, porque si no tendrias el mismo problema entre estas últimas dos), o bien le quitas el `COLLATE = utf8_spanish_ci` a las dos tablas que lo tienen.

He hecho una prueba de concepto corrigiendo esos detalles y no me ha arrojado el error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

#### ¿Qué pasa si aún así sigue fallando?

Dado que has estado ejecutando un `CREATE TABLE` anteriormente, puede que alguna de las tablas ya se haya creado, antes de que la creación de las relaciones fallase. Entonces tienes varias posibilidades.

La más simple, si tus tablas son nuevas **y no tiene ya datos**, sería ejecutar un `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...nombre-de-tabla...` de cada una de ellas, antes del `CREATE TABLE` para empezar de nuevo. **Pero ejecuta eso una sola vez**, para prevenir que tus tablas se crean todas de nuevo con la configuración correcta.

O bien puedes modificar el COLLATE mediante otro tipo de consulta como `ALTER TABLE`, o directamente en la interfaz gráfica de tu DBMS.

**Nota:**

Por lo general no es recomendable relacionar las tablas usando columnas del tipo `VARCHAR`. Para hacerlo debes estar muy seguro de que ese valor representa de manera única cada registro. Y tienen que evaluar también el costo que eso puede suponer en cuanto al rendimiento de la base de datos.

Comment: @sstan buena observación. He editado esa parte puntualizando lo que dice la doc. El problema ocurre con las columnas no-binarias. Si la relación fuese entre dos columnas numéricas las tablas podrían tener `COLLATE` distinto.

Comment: Tienes razón @sstan, enfocado desde el punto de vista de la columna queda mucho más claro. He actualizado ese párrafo, creo que ahora queda más claro.

Comment: Quedó perfecto, gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, una explicación increíble.